# Roles and Permissions Implementation for UI Controls and Controller

Tags: objective-c, iphone, swift, enums, roles

When a user is logged in, App receive the type of user as described in Roles enum. Depending on role, user permissions are defined.
e.g.: Admin user can Create,Edit, delete and archive a task, whereas customer can only Edit and Archive

```
public enum PermissionsType:Int
{
    case Create = 1
    case Edit = 2
    case Delete = 4
    case Archive = 8
}

public enum Roles:Int
{
    case Admin = 0
    case Employee = 1
    case Customer = 2
    case Guest = 4
}
```

Depending on user role I want to enable feature in app e.g. Buttons are enable or disable/hidden.
 I thought to write a protocol as below:

```
protocol Permissions {
    var type: PermissionType {get set}

    /// The permission status.
    func status() -> PermissionStatus
}
public enum PermissionStatus: String {
    case authorized    = "Authorized"
    case denied        = "Denied"
}

class Admin:Permisions {
        var type: PermissionType {get set}
        /// The permission status.
        func status() -> PermissionStatus
}
class Customer:Permisions {
        var type: PermissionType {get set}
        /// The permission status.
        func status() -> PermissionStatus
}
```

Depending on user role after login. App should create instance of Admin or Customer and the feature can be enabled/disabled as described below.

```
createBtn.isHidden = Permission.create
```

Got stuck and need help. Any way to achieve this.
I had tried to refer C# code but could not do it same for swift
https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/723432/Roles-and-Permissions-Implementation-for-UI-Contro

Comment: If you want a role to be authorized for multiple tasks I would use an `OptionType` rather than an `enum` (for `PermissionsType`). Then set the mask for the different types and test for the set bits.

Comment: Thanks.. I will try... Looks a promising solution

Comment: I have around 70 permission which changes the behaviour of app... Will OptionSet support that much as we define it  ShippingOptions(rawValue: 1 << 0), ShippingOptions(rawValue: 1 << 1). I do not think I can go on till 70 shift of bits